# Blurred, bad quality logo

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I'm working on logo design in adobe illustrator. It's typography with border and I have problem. When I export it do png or jpg in small size it looks blurry and overall bad. I'm working on pixel preview in illustrator with all options like Align to pixel grid etc. The simple parts are fixed but i have no idea how to fix all the curves in letters like S, A, E, O ect. Example bellow. Fixed areas after export looks sharply and clean. [image]
Is there any way to create logo from regular font that will look good in small png files?

Comment: You're dealing with anti-alias, you are seeing it because your logo is too small.

Comment: When you save make sure anti-aliasing setting is set to type optimized and NOT art optimized

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the logo for print then say it needs to be 5cm wide by 2cm high, be sure to have the export options set to 300dpi (good for print) not 72dpi (good for web, x2 for retina)

Answer (score 1):

As some commenters have pointed out, the "blurriness" you see on the curves are the result of anti-aliasing due to the low resolution in which you are working; there simply aren't enough pixels to display your logo crisply.

Really the only way to help the "blurriness" caused by antialiasing is to increase the pixel dimensions of the logo. If you need it to be a small image (eg, the logo in the header of a website) then you've probably already done everything that can be done.

PS - if the logo is purely type, you can simply select "type optimized" in the "Save for Web" screen and Illustrator will automatically reduce the unnecessary anti-aliasing (more or less the same thing you've done manually already). This only works for live type though, not outlined type.